# Adding functions to string class in c++

Tags: c++, string, gcc, overloading, c++98

I am using the up to date compiler for gcc. Therefore my code can execute to_String() and stoi() but unfortunately the platform that I am trying to compile my code in has a much previous one and I want to add these two functions into the string class therefore I can use them in my code without any problem.This is one of each example of the errors I get.

```
Cabinet.cpp:93:25: error: 'to_string' was not declared in this scope
 cout << to_string(id) << " not found"<<endl;
```

```
LabOrganizer.cpp: In member function 'void LabOrganizer::findClosest(int, int, int)':
LabOrganizer.cpp:294:38: error: 'stoi' was not declared in this scope
        cc = stoi(arr1[i].substr(1,1))-1;
```

Comment: Have you tried including the namespace, such as `std::to_string` ?

Comment: i am using, `using namespace std` inside every class therefore I think I don't have to use that ? @h0r53

Comment: @AlpE don't do `using namespace std;` and do include the correct headers for the functions you wish to call.

Comment: You're using a separate compiler on the target platform, or cross-compiling for the target?

Comment: separate compiler, I compile it in a server with 1998 gcc compiler but my pc has the latest version of gcc. @aschepler

Comment: `with 1998 gcc ` are you an  archeologist?

Comment: The only practical way of "adding these two functions into the string class" is to update your 1998 standard library and compiler with recent ones. If it cannot be done for whatever reason, you'll need to write in 1998's subset of C++.

Comment: @SergeyA No... unfortunately   my schools servers are from '89 this is the updated version .d

Comment: So the target's C++ library doesn't have these functions. Trying to add functions to `std::string` is an unnecessary complication beyond trying to add the functions themselves to `namespace std`. But the easier way is to use things which are in your target's C++ library, either directly or writing your own functions which provide the simple semantics you want.

Comment: @YakovGalka Yes it can not be updated, So I just wanted to add these two functions manually to the string class therefore I can use it inside my code too. Is it possible?

Comment: @aschepler So you are suggesting instead of overloading the string class I should work with what I have and add a function to the member ?

Comment: Neither of these is a member of `std::string` (or any other class). Nothing prevents you from implementing them, but put them in your own (or the global) namespace.

Comment: Note: A lot of people think *I am using the up to date compiler for gcc.* only to find out that they aren't. Some are even using compilers from a decade ago, not realizing they only have the most recent from a particular distribution or the one bundled with the most recent version of an IDE. Rather than saying most recent, give the version number so that you'll always be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two functions aren't part of the "string class". All you need is to use alternatives that existed in 1998:

- The `to_string` function isn't even needed in this context. You can simply change it to:

  ```
  cout << id << " not found" << endl;
  ```
- You can replace `stoi` with `atoi`. It doesn't throw exceptions if the conversion fails, but since it's a school assignment -- you most probably don't care about that:

  ```
  cc = atoi(arr1[i].substr(1,1).c_str())-1;
  ```

If you have many instances whose replacement is too cumbersome, you can, of course, define those functions in some common header file:

```
template<class T>
std::string to_string(const T &x) {
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << x;
    return s.str();
}

inline int stoi(const std::string &s) {
    // ... ignores error handling ...
    return atoi(s.c_str());
}
```

Hopefully this compiles with that 1998 GCC.

Comment: you are simply the best thank you .)